# Ember.js: How to dispaly only a part of model in template?

Tags: ember.js, grunt-ember-templates

In a template:

```
{{#each displayVideos}}   

Index:   {{_view.contentIndex}}

{{/each}}
```

It will display all item in model.

But I want to display only some item depend on index(ex: Display item if index%2==0).

Any idea about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a computed property in your controller, that will only return every second row, and iterate over that instead...

Something like:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    everySecondRow: function() {
        //code to only return every second row
    }.property('model')
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each controller.everySecondRow}} ... {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had found this solution myself yesterday...!

Answer (score 0):

We can use helpers also. Here is an [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gened/3/edit).